# How align Radio group with TextField in Material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I have read the docs, but I am having difficulty how styling works in Material UI.

Basically I have the following radio-group component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio'
import RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup'
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel'
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl'
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel'

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        '& .MuiFormLabel-root': {
            color: 'red',
        },
    },

    formControl: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3),
    },
}))

const RadioInput = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    const { label, value, setValue, name, inputs } = props

    return (
        <FormControl component="fieldset" className={classes.root}>
            <FormLabel component="legend">{label}</FormLabel>
            <RadioGroup
                aria-label={name}
                name={name}
                value={value}
                onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
                row
            >
                {inputs.map((x, index) => {
                    return (
                        <FormControlLabel
                            key={index}
                            value={x.toLowerCase()}
                            control={<Radio />}
                            label={x}
                        />
                    )
                })}
            </RadioGroup>
        </FormControl>
    )
}

export default RadioInput
```

Now, I also have a component for text fields as follows:

```
import React from 'react'

import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core'

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        '& .MuiTextField-root': {
            margin: theme.spacing(1),
            width: 300,
        },
    },
}))

const TextInput = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    const { label, value, setValue, error, type, helperText } = props

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <TextField
                label={label}
                error={!!error ? true : false}
                value={value}
                onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
                helperText={!!error ? error : helperText}
                type={type}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default TextInput
```

The issue is, putting these together I get the following ugly display:

[image]

As you can see the radio button sits slightly to the right of the text field above. What I would like is the labels to be aligned, and the radio buttons to also be to the left in line with the labels.

Could someone please help me out here? I spent some time looking at the docs but made no progress.

Comment: You have a margin of 24px (`theme.spacing(3)`) on your RadioGroup and a margin of 8px (`theme.spacing(1)`) on the TextField.

Comment: Thanks @RyanCogswell, any idea how can I got about fixing that? I can't seem to figure it out from the docs. Changing ```theme.spacing(3)``` to ```theme.spacing(1)``` has no effect.

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.

Comment: Thanks @RyanCogswell, I have created it here. I seem to have fixed the alignment for the labels, but the radio buttons are still slightly indented: https://codesandbox.io/s/young-lake-6he87

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sandbox, you had the following in RadioInput.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import Radio from "@material-ui/core/Radio";
import RadioGroup from "@material-ui/core/RadioGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormLabel";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    color: "red",
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  }
}));

const RadioInput = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { label, value, setValue, name, inputs } = props;

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset" className={classes.root}>
      <FormLabel component="legend">{label}</FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup
        className={classes.root}
        aria-label={name}
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        row
      >
        {inputs.map((x, index) => {
          return (
            <FormControlLabel
              key={index}
              value={x.toLowerCase()}
              control={<Radio />}
              label={x}
            />
          );
        })}
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default RadioInput;
```

The radio group is indented further than the text field and its label because you are specifying `className={classes.root}` (which includes an 8px margin) on both the `FormControl` and the `RadioGroup`, so the `RadioGroup` is indented 8px further than the rest of the contents of the `FormControl`. If you remove `className={classes.root}` from the `RadioGroup` then everything lines up:

```
import React from "react";
import Radio from "@material-ui/core/Radio";
import RadioGroup from "@material-ui/core/RadioGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormLabel";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    color: "red",
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  }
}));

const RadioInput = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { label, value, setValue, name, inputs } = props;

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset" className={classes.root}>
      <FormLabel component="legend">{label}</FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup
        aria-label={name}
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        row
      >
        {inputs.map((x, index) => {
          return (
            <FormControlLabel
              key={index}
              value={x.toLowerCase()}
              control={<Radio />}
              label={x}
            />
          );
        })}
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default RadioInput;
```

[image: Edit RadioGroup and TextField alignment]